# Idris: proof that specific terms are impossible

Tags: idris

Idris version: `0.9.16`

---

I am attempting to describe constructions generated from a `base` value and an iterated `step` function:

```
namespace Iterate
  data Iterate : (base : a) -> (step : a -> a) -> a -> Type where
    IBase : Iterate base step base
    IStep : Iterate base step v -> Iterate base step (step v)
```

Using this I can define `Plus`, describing constructs from iterated addition of a `jump` value:

```
namespace Plus
  Plus : (base : Nat) -> (jump : Nat) -> Nat -> Type
  Plus base jump = Iterate base (\v => jump + v)
```

Simple example uses of this:

```
namespace PlusExamples
  Even : Nat -> Type; Even = Plus 0 2
  even0 : Even 0; even0 = IBase
  even2 : Even 2; even2 = IStep even0
  even4 : Even 4; even4 = IStep even2

  Odd  : Nat -> Type; Odd  = Plus 1 2
  odd1 : Odd 1; odd1 = IBase
  odd3 : Odd 3; odd3 = IStep odd1

  Fizz : Nat -> Type; Fizz = Plus 0 3
  fizz0 : Fizz 0; fizz0 = IBase
  fizz3 : Fizz 3; fizz3 = IStep fizz0
  fizz6 : Fizz 6; fizz6 = IStep fizz3

  Buzz : Nat -> Type; Buzz = Plus 0 5
  buzz0 : Buzz 0; buzz0 = IBase
  buzz5 : Buzz 5; buzz5 = IStep buzz0
  buzz10 : Buzz 10; buzz10 = IStep buzz5
```

The following describes that values below the `base` are impossible:

```
  noLess : (base : Nat) ->
           (i : Fin base) ->
           Plus base jump (finToNat i) ->
           Void
  noLess Z     FZ     m     impossible
  noLess (S b) FZ     IBase impossible
  noLess (S b) (FS i) IBase impossible
```

And the following for values between `base` and `jump + base`:

```
  noBetween : (base : Nat) ->
              (predJump : Nat) ->
              (i : Fin predJump) ->
              Plus base (S predJump) (base + S (finToNat i)) ->
              Void
  noBetween b Z     FZ     m     impossible
  noBetween b (S s) FZ     IBase impossible
  noBetween b (S s) (FS i) IBase impossible
```

---

I am having trouble defining the following function:

```
noJump : (Plus base jump n -> Void) -> Plus base jump (jump + n) -> Void
noJump f m = ?noJump_rhs
```

That is: if `n` isn't `base` plus a natural multiple of `jump`, then neither is `jump + n`.

If I ask Idris to case split `m` it only shows me `IBase` - then I get stuck.

Would someone point me in the right direction?

---

**Edit 0:**
Applying `induction` to `m` gives me the following message:

```
Induction needs an eliminator for Iterate.Iterate.Iterate
```

---

**Edit 1:**
Name updates and here is a copy of the source: http://lpaste.net/125873

Comment: I think that in its current form, the theorem is false. E.g. `Plus 5 3 2` is false, but `Plus 5 3 (3 + 2) :~: Plus 5 3 5` is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a good reason to get stuck on the `IBase` case of this proof, which is that the theorem is false! Consider:

```
noplus532 : Plus 5 3 2 -> Void
noplus532 IBase impossible
noplus532 (IStep _) impossible

plus535 : Plus 5 3 (3 + 2)
plus535 = IBase
```

Answer (score 0):

To **Edit 0:** to induct on a type, it needs a special qualifier:

```
%elim data Iterate = <your definition>
```

To the main question: sorry that I haven't read through all your code, I only want to make some suggestion for falsifying proofs. From my experience (I even delved the standard library sources to find out some help), when you need to prove `Not a` (`a -> Void`), often you can use some `Not b` (`b -> Void`) and a way to convert `a` to `b`, then just pass it to the second proof. For example, a very simple proof that one list cannot be prefix of another if they have different heads:

```
%elim data Prefix : List a -> List a -> Type where
    pEmpty : Prefix Nil ys
    pNext  : Prefix xs ys -> Prefix (x :: xs) (x :: ys)

prefixNotCons : Not (x = y) -> Not (Prefix (x :: xs) (y :: ys))
prefixNotCons r (pNext _) = r refl
```

In your case, I suppose you need to combine several proofs.